# How to fix sound multiple oscillators playing at the same time with javascript web audio api

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api, mobile-chrome

I'm building an sound installation with multiples oscillators playing at the same time (at most there would be 5/6 of them playing at a given time).
It works normally on desktop in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari it does a horrible "kkrkrkrkrkrkrkrkrkr" sound if i play more than one oscillator at a time. I've used the same computer to test it, so it's not a problem with the speakers. On phone, it works on iphone, but on an android it does the same "krkrkrkr" effect if there is more several oscillator, whatever browser i use. 
The end goal of the installation is to be displayed on phones and i can't control which browsers will be used

Here is a simplified version of the code

```
let audioContext;
let touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

let oscillators = [];


window.addEventListener(touchEvent, makeSound);

function makeSound(){
    audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

    createOsc(43.653528929125486);
    createOsc(220);
    createOsc(164.81377845643496);

    currentTime = audioContext.currentTime;
    oscillators.forEach(function(oscillator){
        currentTime = audioContext.currentTime;
        oscillator.start(currentTime);
        oscillator.stop(currentTime + 2);
    });


}

function createOsc(freq){
    oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
    oscillator.frequency.value = freq;
    oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);
    oscillators.push(oscillator);
}
```

I've tried using the ChannelMergerNode but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a difference between Chrome/Firefox and Safari in the way they handle signals which do exceed the range from -1 to +1.

If you connect all three oscillators the signal can theoretically reach a maximum of -3 and +3.

If you make sure that the signal always stays in the range from -1 to +1 by adding a GainNode with a gain of about 0.333 (1 / number of oscillators) all browsers sound the same.

I updated your snippet to add such a GainNode:

```
let audioContext;
let gainNode;
let touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
let oscillators = [];

window.addEventListener(touchEvent, makeSound);

function makeSound(){
    audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

    gainNode = audioContext.createGain();

    gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

    createOsc(43.653528929125486);
    createOsc(220);
    createOsc(164.81377845643496);

    const currentTime = audioContext.currentTime;
    oscillators.forEach(function(oscillator){
        // The next line is probably not needed.
        // currentTime = audioContext.currentTime;
        oscillator.start(currentTime);
        oscillator.stop(currentTime + 2);
    });
}

function createOsc(freq){
    const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();

    oscillator.frequency.value = freq;
    oscillator.connect(gainNode);
    oscillators.push(oscillator);

    gainNode.gain.value = 1 / oscillators.length;
}
```